# Firebase Recycler View Adapter

Tags: android, firebase, listview, firebase-realtime-database

We have a traditional ListView interfaced with a RecyclerView Adapter and a Model class. When we log in to Firebase we navigate to the ListView nothing is loaded in the ListView. We then go back to the login activity and repeat the process
Then all the data is loaded from a very simple DB child node Table List
We tired the Firebase RecyclerAdapter with no luck we may have had the wrong UI or version. Our question is why do we need to make two trips to the list view to load the data? We will post the ListView code NO Errors are generated We did try placing the code in an OnStart method no luck with that

```
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    dbRef = db.child("Table List");

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                listArrayList.add(child.getValue(String.class));
            sz = listArrayList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    sz = listArrayList.size();

    if(sz == 0){
        tvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvNoData.setText("No Quiz's Found\n\nClick On Make New Quiz");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new TableTrackerAdapter(this,listArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    if(sz > 0){
        tvNoData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new TableTrackerAdapter(this,listArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen how do we find that TAG it does not show

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for that is because Firebase database is asynchronous, in other words the recyclerview is getting populated with an empty arraylist before firebase is finished loading data, I faced similar problem before.

Just move everything that depends on your arraylist inside firebase datachange, and the problem will be fixed like this.

```
public void setupRecyclerView(){

    if(sz == 0){
        tvNoData.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        tvNoData.setText("No Quiz's Found\n\nClick On Make New Quiz");

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new TableTrackerAdapter(MainActivity.this,listArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    if(sz > 0){
        tvNoData.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycleview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        mAdapter = new TableTrackerAdapter(MainActivity.this,listArrayList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }
}

db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
dbRef = db.child("Table List");
dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot != null){
            for (DataSnapshot child : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                listArrayList.add(child.getValue(String.class));
            }
        sz = listArrayList.size();
        setupRecyclerView();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: I tried that and the context issue pops up with this line of code mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

Comment: instead of (this) put your activityname.this like mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

Comment: you also have the option to take mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this); and 
 mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager); outside firebase on datachange, and put it before firebase, Also I recommend that you use addListenerForSingleValueEvent instead of addValueEventListener, because you will only connect once in log in time to load data. it will save you concurrent connections.

Comment: Well the RED went away and now we have this error will work to fix cannot be cast to android.content.Context

Comment: ok try to put everything inside a thread let's call it private void setupRecyclerview() {everything here} then in firebase on datachange right under sz = listArrayList.size(); call that method.

Comment: also make sure to check that dataSnapshot is not empty before executing anything like this if(dataSnapshot != null){then your code here}

Comment: so this is a method setupRecyclerView() called from onCreate ? Or is all that code still in onCreate

Comment: the method is called from within firebase onDatachange, we moved it outside as a work around in order not to get context errors, as for the method itself, you should put it outside onCreate.

Comment: Thanks shameless plug We write this app with SQLite Db you can find it here https://androidstackoverflow.com/

Comment: here is an example, a snap from my application, i did the same solution. https://ibb.co/dp7pGT  wow great link thanks, i am a noob too, and I am planning to learn SQLite DB to make a note application :).